# Free iOS library to scan PDF417 barcodes

Tags: gratis, library, ios, scanning, barcode

Are there any free scanning libraries **with PDF417 capability** available to integrate with iOS apps?

[image: PDF417 barcode]

If it supports Android, then that would be even great.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**RMScannerView**](https://github.com/iRareMedia/RMScannerView):

> Simple barcode scanner UIView subclass for iOS apps. Quickly and efficiently scans a large variety of barcodes using the iOS device's built in camera.

It is the only free project I've found that supports also PDF417 barcodes:

> Scan Aztec, Code 128, Code 39, Code 39 Mod 43, Code 93, EAN13, EAN8, **PDF417**, QR, and UPCE codes.

I tried it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The current AVFoundation support PDF417 metadata. Too late to answer but if this is still required, AVFoundation solves the issue. Just add the following code to the scanning session:

```
let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

 metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
 metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.pdf417]
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Answering any later is okay.